# How to write to a compressed file in spring-batch

Tags: java, compression, spring-batch

I'm investigating using spring batch for importing and exporting data between flat files and a database.  I know what I'm trying to do is going to be easy, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.  What I'm trying to do is have data read from the database and written to a compressed file.  Note, I don't want to write all of the data to an uncompressed file and then run a further step to compress this.  I need to write the compressed file as the only output of the process.

In my head I got a pipeline image in my head, which may be blinding me to the batch way of doing this.  Should I be creating a custom ZippedFileItemWriter?  How do I chain a FlatFileItemWriter and a Zipping version together?  Is there some other mechanism that's better suited to this?

Any pointers would be gratefully received.  I'm a little surprised that this isn't something that would be part of the core framework; it doesn't appear to be such a mad idea.  Maybe it is and I'm just missing it.

Regards,

mipper

Comment: if it is (text) line based it could work with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html, it certainly does work for reading, see: http://php.sabscape.com/blog/?p=281

Comment: @MichaelPralow Again, I'm not asking about how to compress the data, I'm asking about the correct/best way of incorporating this into the batch workflow.

Comment: you need a custom writer, additionally you could open a JIRA ticket to make the existing FlatFileItemWriter extensible (same like reader, provide factory setter for the BufferedWriter)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matthias' answer but I think 1-step solution is not restartable. Do you have some requirements of restartability?
Look at [append-to-a-compressed-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046011/append-to-a-compressed-stream)

Comment: I have no complex restart requirements.  If for some reason the process failed (and it would pretty much only be because the database was down or I'd run out of disk space neither of which is particularly recoverable from) I would just restart the process from the beginning.  In fact I would have to restart from the beginning to pick up any updates which might have occured on the DB since the original extract process commenced.

Comment: If so, you just need a custom implementation of 'ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<T>' that write to a compressed OutputStream